# Continuous variable probability

Tags: probability

I'm having an hard time understanding this question and how to solve it:

The weekly search for gasoline in some place, in tens of thousands of liters is a an aleatory variable $X$ with $E[X^2]=\frac{25}{6}$ and function of probability density of:

$
\begin{cases}
x-1 & 1\leq x \leq 2 \\
3-x & 2\leq x \leq 3 \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$

If the place is refilled at the beginning of each week, what's the minimum amount of gasoline that the place needs to have so that there is no lack of gasoline at least for 92% of the weeks.

This is so confusing... 
I don't know where to start
My idea was to apply the central limit theorem to $100$ weeks considering the mean value of the distribution. But I don't think my interpretation is correct... Can someone help me understand the problem better?
The answer should be $2.6$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to find $a$ such that

$$\Pr(X<a) = 0.92. $$

For $a\in(2,3)$, we have that

\begin{align}\Pr(X<a)=&\;\int_1^2 (x-1) dx +\int_2^a (3-x) dx \\[2ex]
=&\; \left[\frac{x^2}{2}+x\right]_1^2+\left[3x-\frac{x^2}{2}\right]_2^a\\[2ex]
=&\;-0.5a^2+3a-3.5.
\end{align}

Solving the polynomial $$-0.5a^2+3a-3.5=0.92$$ yields $a=2. 6$ or $a=3.4$. Since $a\in(2,3)$ it must be that $a=2. 6$.